# Magento 2 : Required Field (UiComponent) (only/any one from two)

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, field, required

> I want to set anyone field is required from two fields [UiComponent]

[image]

for example, either **text field** or **Image** anyone needs to a required field otherwise can not save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage this validation by trick while saving data

In save controller you should check condition for blank data

```
if(!$Data['textfield'] && !isset($Data['image'])){
          $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage(
                    __(
                        'please add image or text.'
                    )
                );
        $this->_redirect('*/*/add');
        return;
}
```